# Android bluetooth game out of synchronization

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth game app, the architecture is much like the BluetoothChat app in the API Demo, except that in stead of sending messages, two players send a "thing" to each other to play the game.

To simplify let's say for example, two players both choose one of enum {Red, Green, Blue}, and push Send button to send via bluetooth message mechanism. The game they play is say "same" if both player chose same enum, or "not same" otherwise. Sorry, you know why I hide this, and I hope it does not affect the discussion.

The enum are represented by buttons, like

```
redButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             myColor = Red;
        }
```

Send button is like

```
send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

               sendChoiceViaBluetooth();
               //inside this method I used some stuff from the 
               //BluetoothChat API Demo to send the choice
        }
```

if I hit a different "color" button after send button, I can resend a new choice.

And there is a judge() method like this

```
if (myColor != null && otherColor != null){

    compareColors();
    showResult();
    myColor = null;
    otherColor =null;
}
```

Both myColor and otherColor are null in the begining, and are reset in the end of judge().

The problem is if I play on both device very fast for many plays, or sometimes I just don't know why, the game will be out of synch. i.e. I send a color from device A only, device B makes a judge(), but not device A, then I go to Device B and send a color, device A makes a judge, but nothing on device B. Both sides seems a make a judge from an "otherColor" from last session. This can continue, but sometimes it just goes away after a while.

I think somewhere something might be out of synch, but I don't know where. Many of the communication methods are just from BluetoothChatService.java in the API Demo, which are mostly synchronized.

Can someone point a direction for me to look for answer? where should I check, etc? Sorry for the lengthy post, the actual code is worse but I tried to simplify the situation.

..........................................................
I found out the bug is probably due to transmission lost. Let's say play A and B both compare localColor and remoteColor to get result. If player A sends his color to B but it is LOST, then at this moment the game status is like this: (v means selection, x means nothing)

```
                           A          |              B

Time 1:      localColor   remoteColor | localColor   remoteColor

                v                x          x         x
```

nothing will play.
Now if B select color and send successfully, the status becomes:

```
                           A          |              B

Time 2:      localColor   remoteColor | localColor   remoteColor

                v                v          v         x
```

only A get both selections so only A do a judge(), B does nothing. Out of sync. Next A selection something and only B does judge(), A does nothing.

What should I do to keep Both players at same page? i.e. ensure a local selection be received by other player?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to disable the send button until the results have come back from the other device and the `judge()` has happened, then you can reenable it.

Comment: Thanks. It could solve the problem. I am going to give it a try. But I do not want to disable the send button in case the player change his mind. Let's say, if play A chooses Red, and hit send. Now play A chooses Blue, and hit send before player B does anything. Then Blue should be compared with player B.   i.e. The last choices (if BOTH player hit send) get compared.

Comment: Also, there is no "result". Both players keep sending choices again and again. "result" is obtained locally by the judge() method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only judge when two results are in place, that is to say A could have changed their minds 100 times before B made a choice, then you should only be judging when you have a choice on both sides.

So normally in an action respond kind of way, A sends blue and B chooses Red. The judge then would see two choices and judge. this would require that the judge action actually be synchronized on both devices, or at least have access to both devices choices. (like locking the send button so that it can't be changed until judged.)

It sounds to me that along with the choice you also need to send a judge state so that one device won't judge while the other does not. Furthermore , every response received should echo back the judge state and the choice of the other player(s).

> I send a color from device A only, device B makes a judge(), but not device A, then I go to Device B and send a color, device A makes a judge, but nothing on device B. Both sides seems a make a judge from an "otherColor" from last session.

This would make sense to me if you were not synchronizing the judges or echoing the current choice when you receive a new choice from another player. The judge in A only has the choice A just made, and if it was not cleared for some reason, the choice B made the last time you judged.

In the above example, it could be that the reason why it is is using old data is that you are setting the value on device A while it is being cleared or while it is being checked for empty. this would be a thread safety issue.

I am assuming that judge is running in a separate thread as a worker and is checking the state of those variables almost all the time. If this is the case you need to somehow lock the variable or queue it and have the judge consume the queue as opposed to work with the reactive values. Otherwise there is nothing to stop you from modifying the variable while the judge is trying to clear it.

> Both sides seems a make a judge from an "otherColor" from last session.

This also makes sense because the last session is the only place it has data from if the send event did not get a response or if you are changing the local variable faster than the judge can clear it. This would also be solved if you were to synchronize the judge event.

So to summarize:

- Try synchronizing the judge events if this is what is desired through a handshake.
- Try putting all 'choices' in a queue and consume them in the judge so that you are not entering a race condition where you are checking the variable for empty while assigning it a value.
- Make sure that when the app receives a 'send' event or 'choice', you are echoing back the current choice that the receiving device has made, so there is always a value for that device. Don't judge until you get this response, and if you don't get the response don't judge.

with a little more information I could possibly narrow the answer and really solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Didn't add much to what I already know though.